# Gmail API Resumable Upload for Drafts in C# Desktop Application

Tags: c#, winforms, gmail, gmail-api

I wrote a C# WinForms application that uses the Gmail API to create message drafts with attachments and upload them into Gmail. This worked well until a few months ago. Here is that code:

```
var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
Attachment file = new Attachment(FileLocation);
msg.Attachments.Add(file);

MimeMessage messageMIME = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(msg); //using MimeKit here

Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message m = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();

m.Raw = Base64UrlEncode(messageMIME); //private method for Convert.ToBase64String
Draft draft = new Draft();
draft.Message = m;
service.Users.Drafts.Create(draft, "me").Execute();
```

The above code now only works when the draft message is below 1 MB in size. When the message/attachment exceeds this limit, the code now issues this error:

> Google.GoogleApiException: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
>   Request payload size exceeds the limit: 1048576 bytes. [400]

I believe that Google changed its API so that it now requires using the [resumable upload protocol](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#resumable) for uploading drafts with attachments that exceed 1 MB.

Now the final line in the above code snippet has an overload

```
service.Users.Drafts.Create(draft, "me", stream, @"message/rfc822");
```

[image]

that uses the [CreateMediaUpload Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/csharp/latest/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Gmail_1_1v1_1_1UsersResource_1_1DraftsResource_1_1CreateMediaUpload.html), which allows uploads that support the resumable upload protocol. However, regardless of how I create the draft body or code the stream, I have been unable to correctly use this overload to create and upload drafts of any size. What would be the correct way to structure my code so that this overload works? Or is there some other way to upload draft messages with attachments from a C# desktop app using the resumable upload protocol from the Gmail API? All help is very much appreciated.

**Update**

If I remove the two lines of code that add the attachment, this line of code:

```
service.Users.Drafts.Create(draft, "me", stream, @"message/rfc822").Upload();
```

will create the draft with its body text in Gmail. However, nothing I can think of will create and/or stream the draft's attachment using this overload. I have tried using multipart MIME messages, file streams, memory streams, and attempts with and without base64 encoding in the attachment. Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: your last one try changing @"message/rfc822" to  GetMimeType(_uploadFile);

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion @DaImTo, but still can't get this to work. `System.InvalidOperationException` for `stream.ReadTimeout` and `stream.WriteTimeout`. I am wondering how the stream and the draft body relate to each other. What exactly is supposed to be streamed vs. what is in the draft body? Does this need to be a multi-part MIME message? Is there some other way to declare the upload as resumable? Will continue to explore these and other questions.

Comment: I can't remember tbh I have been digging in the code for the library trying to figure it out :)

Comment: Body is the text.   Stream is the file attachments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never worked with the Google Gmail api in C# before this morning, so I was intrigued by your question. I replicated your attachment issue and solved it with the code below with a successful test email including attachment, so you should be good to go (Please mark as resolved if so, or else let me know in comments if you're still having problems and I'll take an additional look).

Essentially, what I've done is

1. Use a different overload of the Create() method which takes a stream object as a parameter.
2. This different overload is a function, which returns a CreateMediaUpload type.
3. This CreateMediaUpload type has an Upload (and Upload async) method which supports resumable uploads under the hood, thereby bypassing the original message size limitation.

The test file I sent up was 1.6 megabytes, so much higher that the request payload maximum threshold you (and I) were receiving before.

Happy emailing! Again, let me know in the comments if you still have problems... also I'd remove the Debug / Stopwatch / Sending stuff at the end there before putting this into anything production. Its just there for testing.

```
       // Create Gmail API service.
        var service = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });


        var file = new Attachment(FileLocation);

        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        msg.Attachments.Add(file);
        msg.Body = "Tester Body";
        msg.To.Add("MyTestDestinationEmailAddress@Gmail.com");

        MimeMessage messageMIME = MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(msg); //using MimeKit here
         MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        messageMIME.WriteTo(memory);


        Draft draft = new Draft();

        var createRequest = service.Users.Drafts.Create(draft, "me", memory, @"message/rfc822");


        var startTime = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var uploadProgress = createRequest.Upload();

        if (uploadProgress.Status == UploadStatus.Completed)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Elapsed Time: {0}", startTime.Elapsed));
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Status: {0}", uploadProgress.Status.ToString()));
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Bytes Sent: {0}", uploadProgress.BytesSent));

            //to send the draft email, uncomment the lines below

            //draft = createRequest.ResponseBody;
            //var send =  service.Users.Drafts.Send(draft, "me");
            //send.Execute();

        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception: {0}", uploadProgress.Exception.Message));
        }
```

Comment: First let me say thank you @HBomb! Your code works. Just want to add one thing. Your answer states you refactored the base64url encoding, but the code you wrote omits it. And rightly so because when I saw that the encoding wasn't needed I reread  the [GMAIL API Working with Drafts page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/drafts) and the [Gmail APi Uploading Attachments Page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads) and saw that `CreateMediaUpload` uploads binary data as opposed to standard draft creation which requires a base64url encoded string. Much appreciated!

Comment: @joeschwa - No worries, I updated my post to reflect the fact that the encoding was removed. It had existed in a previous version of my code, so I was a bit confused when I wrote that. Thanks for pointing it out! Best, -H